# Have I really been hacked or am I falling for a phishing scam

Tags: account-security, phishing, data-leakage

I received an email on the 14th saying that a hacker has access to my pc it says that at the time of hacking my account (myemail@gmail.com) had this password (it was a version of my password but not one that I’ve ever used for my gmail) and it claimed to have been watching me for months and that it had infected my pc through a adult website and had video of me when I was on the site doing you know what and that it would send it to my contacts and correspondence but I don’t have any contacts on my pc and also I use a different user and email when I do that, also why didn’t it send it to that email and not any of the other emails I have saved on my pc. Am I falling for a bullshit email or do I have something to worry about? Also it said I have 48 hours to pay them in bitcoins and that it would track when I opened it and start the countdown and I just opened it last night

Comment: It is called scam.

Comment: So does that mean I’m safe?

Comment: Who knows... But 99.98% of chance this is scam/joke. If you maintain good computer using practices, it will be very hard to invade your computer. DISCLAIMER: ASSUME NO RESPONSIBILITIES FOR ANY OUTCOME.

Comment: See this recent question: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/206319/90657 this is a very common scam

Answer (score 3):

This is a popular online scam so you should delete the email and move about your business.

See the FBI's Public Service Announcement on this scam specifically.

https://www.ic3.gov/media/2020/200420.aspx

Comment: So for the most part I’m safe?